# Differences between 事実 and 真実

Tags: word-choice, words, meaning

Both 真実 and 事実 means; fact,truth. So in Kanji Lesson I asked my teacher if there is any differences between them, he said yes but there was no time to explain.

Comment: If your dictionary translates 真実 as “fact,” I am afraid that your dictionary is wrong.

Comment: Definitions for [真実](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/detail?p=%E7%9C%9F%E5%AE%9F&stype=0&dtype=3) and [事実](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/detail?p=%E4%BA%8B%E5%AE%9F&stype=0&dtype=3) (Progressive Japanese-English Dictionary)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the kanji to break it down.

`事実`　→　`事` = thing; `実` = true.  So it's a "true thing", "something that is true"; a fact as opposed to a false statement.  Exs.

> - 空は青いです　→　The sky is blue; this is a fact
> - 太陽は東から昇り西に没する　→　The sun rises in the east and sets in the west; this is also a fact
> - 事実無根　→　(a) groundless (fact)

`真実`　→　`真` = true, real; `実` = true, truth.  So this is truth as an abstract concept, as opposed to a lie.

> - 真実を言え！　→　Tell the truth
> - 彼の言うことの真実性を疑う　→　I doubt the truth in what he says.